# Mozy and others are there, but any to backup multiple computers

Tags: backup, online-backup

I read few posts on this forum on remote backup services. IDrive and Mozy provide FREE service to backup from single PC. Is there any service through which I can backup data from any computer, as I travel often? If it is paid one, then will do, but under budget. The service must also be trusted and reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citadel Remote Backup allows you to map drives from the server. I use Citadel Remote Backup for a few other reasons: Security 448-bit Blowfish Encryption — Safely secure your data during backup and restore. Monitoring — State-of-the-art Backup power systems & Monitoring. Compliant — Compliant with HIPAA, Sarbanes-Oxley, PCI-DSS and others. Certified Technicians — All our technicians are Microsoft certified experts, unlike levels of support at our competitors.

Performance Automatic or Scheduled backups — Automatic is the simplest method in which backups are performed while your computer is not in use. Scheduled backups can be performed as defined basis requirement. Incremental backups — Saves bandwidth and ensures future backups are lightning fast.

Ease of Use SQL, SQL Express, MS Exchange & DBMS support — Brick-level exchange backup, supports workstation & server Packages Supported — Citadel Backup supports Windows (2000, XP, 2003, and Vista, including servers), SharePoint, Active directory, System state backup and recovery. Open/Locked File Support — Backs up all open and locked files, including Outlook PST files and folders Free Trial Version — Full version free trial including technical support for you to test the solution. They're at http://www.CitadelBackup.com

Answer (score 2):

I use Backblaze on multiple computers for continuous backup. Being able to restore selected files or directories online is great. But it's a similar service to Mozy.

If you are looking for an easy way to backup specific files from random computers, check out Dropbox, http://www.getdropbox.com/. You can install the client on as many machines as you'd like. It will create a special folder, and anything you copy into that folder will automatically synch to all other machines with the client installed. You can also access your dropbox from their website, and upload files via the web interface.

Plus, Dropbox allows free storage (and full use) for your first 2GB. Good for the budget.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for dropbox - 2GB free, up to 100GB paid. Shared and replicated on all your machines, and also an iphone client, an android client, a blackberry client, and a web client.

You mentioned traveling so I think the ability to pull up a file on your phone or on a website would be a huge benefit to you. (the dropbox phone apps will preview files- I can also say from experience that you can use dropbox on the ipad to open files in other ipad apps (for example you can open a pdf in your dropbox account in goodreader on the ipad.

Best of all, Dropbox has been rock solid for me on both mac and windows. I have never had a problem with dropbox ever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Live Mesh](https://www.mesh.com/welcome/default.aspx)? It only offers 5 GB, but it's quite a good service; works on Windows and Mac OS X.